# How do I remove excessive spaces between characters in java String

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I am pulling text from a file and for some reason it is formatted with extra whitespace between each character(ex: "H i ,  I  a m  a  S t r i n g .").

Is there a way I can cleanly remove the excess white space something like

```java
public String cleanString(Sting string){
    //do Something
    return cleanedString;
}
String oldString = "1  :  H i ,  I ' a m  a  S t r i n g .";

System.out.println(cleanString(oldString));
```

`Output: "1: Hi, I'am a String."`

Edit: By excessive spaces/white space I mean the extra space between every character in the string including the valid spaces.

I am replacing the "excessive space" with • so it is more visible
String -> "H•e•l•l•o• •W•o•r•l•d"
Imagine that the • is just white space or the "space" character. I would like to remove them.

The extra spaces are indeed spaces and not null characters, I double checked that.

Comment: You'll have to first propose some logic by which your program should decide which spaces to keep. A large part of software development is defining the problem and algorithms for solution in clear terms. Your first step should be to define a clear ruleset by which anyone, including a computer, can decide which of the spaces should be deleted and which ones kept.

Comment: How do you want your program to figure out `I'am a String` instead of `I'amaString`?

Comment: Are you **sure** those extra characters are space characters?  Recently, I saw a Stack Overflow question which observed a similar effect, because someone tried to convert UTF-16 bytes to a String using the platform’s default charset, which happened to be a one-byte windows-12nn charset.  Are you sure your extra characters are space characters and not zero ([NUL](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/)) characters?

Comment: Your example was somewhat trivial.  How do you define excessive spaces?  For example,  `"H e     l   l        o   ,      W  o    r l  d!!"` has excessive spaces.  Would you expect that to be reduced to `"Hello, World!!"`?

Comment: @WJS, my question is specific to the one extra whitespace between characters and normal spaces, but yes your example would be valid as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to substitute `space,not a space` sequence with the second symbol(s) ( `not a space` ).

There are more than one spaces between the words and one space between the letters in the word. With the regular expression `oldString.replaceAll(" ([^ ]+)", "$1")` we are removing any space that is followed by non space character. In that way only spaces is left between words and no spaces left between the letters in the word. Now we can normalize the spaces between words with the following expression:  `newString1.replaceAll("[ ]{2,}", " ")`

Below is the code that doing it:

```
  @Test
  void removeEmptySpaces() {
    final String oldString = "1  :  H i ,  I ' a m  a     S t r i n g .";
    final String expectedString = "1 : Hi, I'am a String.";
    // Trying to substitute all 'space,not a space' sequence with the second symbol(s)
    final String newString1 = oldString.replaceAll(" ([^ ]+)", "$1");
    final String newString = newString1.replaceAll("[ ]{2,}", " ");
    System.out.println(newString); // 1 : Hi, I'am a String.
    Assertions.assertEquals(expectedString, newString);
  }

  }
```

Comment: This is not the expected output from the question.

Comment: @TriphonPenakov, this partially works and it is hard to see in the question but its not a double space but a triple space so it follows the pattern "a character" + "unwanted space" + "valid space" + "unwanted space" + "another character"

Comment: Though I could just run the string threw .replaceAll() again and just have it remove an spaces that are followed by another space

Comment: Hi @cdub - I've edited the answer. Basically added one more substitution to remove more than one spaces: `newString1.replaceAll("[ ]{2,}", " ")`